# How come I can not use my SUPER-L key, or Windows key, in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-10.04, keyboard-layout

For some reason I can not use my left or right SUPER key which is also known as the Windows key. I used to use it to activate some Compiz Fusion effects like Expo by pressing **left SUPER** + **e**.

I have tried to see if I could solve this by going to System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts but I did not see how to solve this there. I did however see that under Action > Desktop there was a **Expo Key** action that had **Mod4+E** as its shortcut. I tried to change a random disabled shortcut to see if I could input **Mod4** by using the SUPER key but when I press the **left SUPER** key I get **XF86MenuKB**. When I tried this with the **right SUPER** key I will get **XF86ScreenSaver**. What are these two shortcuts?

I assume that this is the reason why my SUPER keys are not working. After all when I press them I get **XF86MenuKB** and **XF86ScreenSaver** when I assume I should be getting **Mod4** at least for the left SUPER key.

*Here is a screen shot of some of my keyboard shortcuts. You can see all the shortcuts that start with **XF86**. The ones related to sound I have discovered refer to the set of 6 media buttons on the top of my laptop's keyboard. The other ones below it I do not know about. Also notice the Expo shortcut below.*
[image]

Also I have gone to System > Preferences > Keyboard (Keyboard Preferences) > Layouts (tab) > Options (Keyboard Layout Options) and I selected **Hyper is mapped to Win-keys** but this did not help either. I also did not help when I have it at its default settings.

[image]

So any idea on how to get my right and left **SUPER** keys working again?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to question: [How can I make my Super keys (Windows Key) behave more like Ctrl/Alt/Shift in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/246345/how-can-i-make-my-super-keys-windows-key-behave-more-like-ctrl-alt-shift-in-lin/249578#249578). Maybe it will help you. In short: try `Meta is mapped to Win keys` setting.